# Density of $\frac{1}{X^2}$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I have to answer the following question: If $X$ is a standard Gaussian random variable, what is the density of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{X^2}$?

Wikipedia states: (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables)

If the probability density function of a random variable $X$ is given as $f_{X}(x)$, it is possible to calculate the probability density function of some variable $g(X)$. If the function $g$ is monotonic, then the resulting density function is:

$\displaystyle f_{g(x)}(y)=\left|\frac{d}{dy}\left(g^{-1}(y)\right)\right|\cdot f_{X}\left(g^{-1}(y)\right)$

However $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x^2}$ is not monotonic over the whole line, so can I use this formula in this case, and call $\displaystyle g^{-1}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$,   in which case the answer would be:

$$\displaystyle f_{g(x)}(t)=\left|\left(\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)\right|\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)^2}=     \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2t}}}{2t^{\frac{3}{2}}\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

Using Berci's method,

\begin{align} 
\begin{split}
F_Y(t)     &=P(Y<t)\\
&=P\left(\frac1{X^2} <t \right)\\
&=P\left(|X|>\frac1{\sqrt t}\right)\\
&=2\cdot P\left(X<-\frac1{\sqrt t}\right)\\
&=2\cdot F\left(-\frac1{\sqrt t}\right)\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{-1/\sqrt{t}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}dt
\end{split}     
\end{align}

where the symmetry of the standard Gaussian distribution is used:

$\displaystyle P\left(X<-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)=P\left(X>{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)$. And now, differentiate with respect to $t$:

$$\displaystyle f_{g(x)}(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{-1/\sqrt{t}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}dt=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2t}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}t^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Note that $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2t}}}{2t^{\frac{3}{2}}\sqrt{2\pi}}=1$, as it should be, but

$\displaystyle  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2t}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}t^{\frac{3}{2}}}=2$, so this is not the correct answer.

Why am I missing the factor of $2$ when I solve the problem using the integral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F$ be the *distribution function* of $X$, that is, $F(t)=\int_{-\infty}^tf\,,\ $ where $f$ is the density function of $X$. And $Y:=1/X^2$. Then, for $t>0$, we have
$$F_Y(t)=P(Y<t)=P\left(\frac1{X^2} <t \right)=P\left(|X|>\frac1{\sqrt t}\right)=\\
=2\cdot P\left(X<-\frac1{\sqrt t}\right)=2\cdot F\left(-\frac1{\sqrt t}\right)$$
where the symmetry of the standard Gaussian distribution is used ($P(X<-1/\sqrt t)=P(X>1/\sqrt t)$ ). Then, differentiate it w.r.t. $t$.

Comment: Ok, so $\displaystyle F_Y(t)=2\cdot F\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{-1/\sqrt{t}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}dt$?

Comment: Assuming this is correct, I worked it out using the wikipedia formula and your method. I'm curious what you think, since when I worked it out your way, I was missing a factor of 2.

Comment: I think you missed my last sentence. Differentiate $F_Y(t)$, knowing that $F'=f$, we get
$$f_Y(t)=2\cdot f\left(-\frac1{\sqrt t}\right)\cdot \frac1{2t\sqrt t}\,.$$
And all this is valid for $t>0$, and for $t\le 0$, we have $f_Y(t)=0$ (as $F_Y(t)=0$ already).

Comment: Oh makes perfect sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: $f_Y(t)=2\cdot f\left(-\frac1{\sqrt t}\right)\cdot \frac1{2t\sqrt t} = 2\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)^2}\cdot \frac{1}{2t\sqrt{t}}=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2t}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}t^{3/2}}$